# flow error accessing optional prop after truthy check

Tags: javascript, flowtype

flow 0.67.1 (but behavior continues to exist in 0.73.1)

Example:

```
type PropOptional = {
  prop?: ComplexType
};                         

type ComplexType = {
  callable: () => void,
  anotherCallable: () => void
};

function usePropOptional(arg1: PropOptional) {
  if (arg1.prop) {
    arg1.prop.callable();
    arg1.prop.anotherCallable();
    arg1.prop.callable();
  }
};
```

The function checks for the presence of `arg1.prop` before accessing any properties on `arg1.prop`. This should be sufficient to verify that `arg1.prop` is defined.

Flow is fine with the first time an `arg1.prop` property is accessed, which is the call to `arg1.prop.callable()` on the first line inside the `if` block.  However, flow generates errors on subsequent attempts to access `arg1.prop` properties in the exact same `if` block:

```
arg1.prop.anotherCallable();
arg1.prop.callable();
```

I am forced to either prepend each line with a rote `arg1.prop &&` truthy check, or reassign `arg1.prop` to a local variable inside the if block:

```
function usePropOptional(arg1: PropOptional) {
  if (arg1.prop) {
    const reallyExists = arg1.prop;
    reallyExists.callable();
    reallyExists.anotherCallable();
    reallyExists.callable();
  }
};
```

This doesn't feel right. What am I doing wrong or missing?

You can check this in a [flow repl here on flow.org](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAeTMAlggdgQwDZQC8UA3gFBRRiJgD8AXFAMIIC2YeEAHgCrgRkAvgG5KY8RMkSKU2XLKhIzNh258lxcpQDG+PDgBGnRgAoAlEQB8UAG4J0AEwA0MnFgTAAFhDhM9h4yhzK1t7ByFhMjIAMwBXLG0MbChYgGcIeCRUJNw8Exw4AHMARkZMlDRMXLMtKHRooIKSgDpqJAtayibi1ppm3Tx9IwhzSPFu3qRmtw9vX39h0Zkuop62sH6FziXKQQiouISclPTy7Kr8ACUPCCZvbQBrfNWymnPsfBqZesbVybAOssoBN1ptBgERmYxmIQTQoAAyeHAv6gmZeHx+cGLKFA2FIBFIvEbAZDbY43b7GLxRJVE4ZN6VD54S4QHCpVLoQpYVgQLDAZ4lV5ZRnVWo-AVrGiA8TabCpYBQOCswYgACiXHQ8tSRGRLXW0MoSr0ao1WrBpMhBsVyrwJs1wFS03c6PmWLJVqNKvV9sdJIhOygexEQA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in FlowType's [Type Refinement](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#toc-refinement-invalidations) section:

> Refinement Invalidations
>
> It is also possible to invalidate refinements, for example:
>
> ```
> // @flow
> function otherMethod() { /* ... */ }
>
> function method(value: { prop?: string }) {
>   if (value.prop) {
>     otherMethod();
>     // $ExpectError
>     value.prop.charAt(0);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> The reason for this is that we don’t know that otherMethod() hasn’t
>   done something to our value. 
>   ...
>
> There’s a straightforward way to get around this. Store the value
>   before calling another method and use the stored value instead. This
>   way you can prevent the refinement from invalidating.
>
> ```
> // @flow
> function otherMethod() { /* ... */ }
>
> function method(value: { prop?: string }) {
>   if (value.prop) {
>     var prop = value.prop;
>     otherMethod();
>     prop.charAt(0);
>   }
> }
> ```

So the workaround in your final case appears to be the suggested way to avoid this problem.